# Is it possible to rotate a matrix by 45 degrees in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, orientation

i.e. so that it appears like a diamond. (it's a square matrix) with each row having 1 more element than the row before up until the middle row which has the number of elements equal to the dimensions of the original matrix, and then back down again with each row back to 1?

Comment: Are you asking about visualizing a matrix as a diamond?

Comment: `Matrix = imrotate(Matrix,45);` With Image processing toolbox ?

Comment: This is more to solve a wordsearch with strfind. It's easy for forwards and I use fliplr for backwards and ' for up and down. But I cannot see any way of doing the 4 diagonals except for rotating it 45 degrees and then doing forwards, backwards, up and down with that?

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau That's going to interpolate the values which may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @beaker you're right. But we need more informations about the subject. Nermona, Is it possible to provide some code ? A dum example or something like that ?

Comment: For example, for forwards I did:

    for x = 1:10
        f = strfind(wordGrid(i,:), word);
    end

Comment: maybe [spdiags](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html)?

Comment: @beaker, correct, `char(spdiags(c))'` gives the diagonals in one direction, and `char(spdiags(rot90(c)))'` those in the other direction, padded with \0 characters. Why don't you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A rotation is of course not possible as the "grid" a matrix is based on is regular.

But I remember what your initially idea was, so the following will help you:

```
%example data
A = magic(5);

A =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

---

```
d = length(A)-1;
diamond = zeros(2*d+1);

for jj = d:-2:-d

    ii = (d-jj)/2+1;
    kk = (d-abs(jj))/2;

    D{ii} = { [zeros( 1,kk ) A(ii,:) zeros( 1,kk ) ] };
    diamond = diamond + diag(D{ii}{1},jj);
end
```

will return the diamond:

```
diamond =

     0     0     0     0    17     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0    23     0    24     0     0     0
     0     0     4     0     5     0     1     0     0
     0    10     0     6     0     7     0     8     0
    11     0    12     0    13     0    14     0    15
     0    18     0    19     0    20     0    16     0
     0     0    25     0    21     0    22     0     0
     0     0     0     2     0     3     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     9     0     0     0     0
```

Now you can again search for words or patterns row by row or column by column, just remove the zeros then:

Imagine you extract a single row:

```
row = diamond(5,:)
```

you can extract the non-zero elements with `find`:

```
rowNoZeros = row( find(row) )

rowNoZeros =

    11    12    13    14    15
```

---

Not a real diamond, but probably useful as well:

(Idea in the comments by @beaker. I will remove this part, if he is posting it by himself.)

```
B = spdiags(A)

B =

    11    10     4    23    17     0     0     0     0
     0    18    12     6     5    24     0     0     0
     0     0    25    19    13     7     1     0     0
     0     0     0     2    21    20    14     8     0
     0     0     0     0     9     3    22    16    15
```

Comment: This is great thank you. Although one more question, how do I remove / not count the zeros?

Comment: Glad that I could help! accepting answers will keep people doing that ;)