# Does Matlab have a function similar to strfind

Tags: matlab, matrix

But instead of returning just one index if the String matches, it returns the element of the searched matrix according to the word's first letter?

For example, if I had a 20 by 20 matrix of ints and contained within that matrix was the sequence: 3, 34, 6, 7, 8. and say if I used strfind with this matrix and was searching it for an identical String of Ints it would return the column of the matrix that it starts with. But I want it to return the row as well.

I was initially thinking, because I use a for loop to process each row, the value of i will be the row, but I am struggling to implement it?

Comment: Show us the code you've got so far! It will make it easier to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do some math. `strfind` requires a single-row vector, you can easily achieve that with the colon operator `:` - then you use the position to calculate row and column index.

example data:

```
A = char('a'+ randi(26,5,5) -1)

A =

ftyqa
foxuk
iijtt
cvodu
tojvj
```

Now have a look where `'x'` is located:

```
[m,n] = size(A);
pos = strfind(A(:)','x');
column = ceil(pos/m);
row = mod(pos-1,m)+1;

column =

     3


row =

     2
```

Also have a look at `regexpi`, maybe helpful as it also returns the index of the last letter.

```
[start,end] = regexpi(A(:)','myWord')
```

---

**To hopefully end this wordsearch algorithm madness, try this guys:**

First transform your char matrix to integers from `1 to 26`, also the words you're actually looking for.

example:

```
A = reshape(1:25,5,5)'
A =

     1     6    11    16    21
     2     7    12    17    22
     3     8    13    18    23
     4     9    14    19    24
     5    10    15    20    25

[m,n] = size(A)
```

sequence, word whatever:

```
sequence = [8 9 10];

[~,I] = intersect(A,sequence)
```

indices of sequence:

```
I =  8  9  10
```

finally check if its actually a valid sequence:

```
dI = diff(sort(I))
validSequence =  ( numel(sequence) == sum(dI)+1 ...
                && numel(sequence) <= mod(I(end)-1,m)+1 )

validSequence =     1
```

The other cases would be:

```
sequence = [13 10 11];

validSequence =     0   %violates 1st condition

sequence = [9 10 11];

validSequence =     0   %violates 2nd condition
```

---

In the next steps you need `fliplr`,`flipud`,`transpose` and my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380587/is-it-possible-to-rotate-a-matrix-by-45-degrees-in-matlab/20381889#20381889) to finish the algorithm.

Comment: Lol I'm not nermona, but looking at their activity they seem to be on my uni course!

Comment: Also, I did a little bit of extra experimenting and found a way that works if I break out of the loop, but I do not know if this is a bad thing to do?

Comment: And yes I know. Although having just started the assignment their questions were v. helpful lol!

Comment: have a look at my edit and share it with your colleagues - how more are about to come? ;)

Comment: do you have an email address? I'd like to send my code for you to check something?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's obviously a homework and I'm not going to check it. You can try it here: [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No it's an assignment.

Comment: Practically the same ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk CR would be the best place to get the code reviewed, [if it were working code](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)...

Answer (score 0):

The answer by thewaywewalk seems more elegant, but you can also use `strfind` with a cell array as the first argument.  Just convert the matrix into a cell array via `mat2cell` where each cell is a row in the matrix.

Data:

```
M = randi(25,20,20);
s = M(sub2ind(size(M),[4 4 4],[3 4 5])); % sequence at row 4, columns 3 to 5
```

Search:

```
>> c = mat2cell(char(M),ones(size(M,1),1),size(M,2));
>> matches = strfind(c,char(s));
>> row = find(~cellfun(@isempty,matches))
row =
     4
>> col = matches{row}
col =
     3
```

Comment: @user3071257 Your welcome!  But no bump up?  ;) Or are you not allowed to use `char`?